# Truffle test remain in "pending" status

Tags: truffle, ganache, truffle-test

I've a smart contract under test, which exposes a public property of type `address` bestSeller:

```
contract Club {
    address public owner;
    uint public price; //price to join the Club
    uint public membersCount;
    uint public bestSale; //the best sale till now
    address public bestSeller; //the user who presented more users
```

so now I reduced my test to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem, and it looks like:

```
it("report correctly the best seller"),async () => {

  let bestSeller =  await instance.bestSeller.call();
 })
```

all the test works, except this one that remain in "pending", as reported by truffle test:

[image]

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 it("report correctly the best seller"), async () => {
     let bestSeller =  await instance.bestSeller.call();
 } // guess you didn't have ')' here, cause if it were there, it does not run
```

to

```
 it("report correctly the best seller", async () => {
     let bestSeller =  await instance.bestSeller.call();
 })
```

Watch out for the parenthesis!